# Trying to install GIT on CentOS 5 and a little lost

Tags: git, centos, dedicated-server

I am a little over my head with this but I guess you have to start somewhere. I would like to use GIT on my 1and1 dedicated server.

From what I have read searching Google I had to create a file named: epel.repo which has this in it:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/$basearch
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-5&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-debug-5&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/SRPMS
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-source-5&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
gpgcheck=1
```

And place it on this directory: /etc/yum.repos.d/

That worked just fine but i'm getting a message that reads:

```
GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 5] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL'
```

IS there something that I missed in doing like add another file in that directory specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by reading the [EPEL documentation](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F) rather than random pages found via Google.  The documentation tells you what you need to install in order for things to work.

The error you're getting is pretty clear.  The repository definition you've created includes:

```
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
```

And I'm guessing that files doesn't exist on your system.  You could google that key name and install it by hand, but it's easier to follow the EPEL project instructions and simply install the appropriate version of their `epel-release` package.  This will get you the correct repository definitions AND the appropriate GPG keys.

Answer (score 36):

You can solve this error by creating File named "" under "/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/".

Go into rpm-gpg directory

```
cd /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/
```

Download GPG KEYS from https://fedoraproject.org/keys

```
wget https://fedoraproject.org/static/217521F6.txt
```

Rename to "217521F6.txt" to "RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL"

```
cp 217521F6.txt RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
```

Remove "217521F6.txt" because we don't need in that file anymore

```
rm 217521F6.txt
```

If you want you can remove prefix lines from the file by vim and :wq (:Write and Quit)

```
vim RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
```

Try again installing git git-daemon

```
yum install git git-daemon
```

I believe, these will solve given error.

Answer (score 5):

Less condescending version of answer #1: The epel page linked has an rpm which will magically do the setup for you. I am using CentOS 5.8, so I grabbed the one for Enterprise Linux 5, EPEL5.
Some windows managers will just take care of the install for you. Mine did.
If you must, wget the rpm and then install it with rpm -ivh filename.
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F

Answer (score 0):

**Those worked with me right away**

```
## RHEL/CentOS 6 64 Bit OS ## 
# wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm 
# rpm -Uvh rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

# wget http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt 
# rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
```

This problem and so many similar ones will vanish!!